# How could I link these nails to the animation?

Tags: animation, objects, .fbx

[image]I have no clue how to ask this but I feel like its pretty important and I'm not sure how you do it in blender.

The picture says a lot, I want the nails on the head moving with the figure which is only slow head movement (up and a bit down), very easy to track. Not sure how I could link them though.

Comment: Parent them to your main object with 'Keep Offset'? [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#parenting-objects) is the Blender entry on parenting.

Comment: If you are on a newer version of Blender you might want to look at the current version's manual: [Parenting Objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/parent.html)

Comment: Oops! I don't know why the Blender Manual lookup thought I was on 2.79 as I was actually using 4.0.1 at the time! Thanks Gordon!